# Remove last character of specific rows ending with '.'

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple csv files with the same kind of data to be merged on the rows to form a single dataframe but some of the row names have dirty data.

For example '.' at the end of the actual name.
I tried the below code -

```
for file in all_files:
temp = pd.read_csv(file, encoding = "unicode_escape")
temp = temp[['S.No.', 'Item', '2014-15']]
state = lambda x: x.split('-')
temp.rename(columns = {'2014-15':state(file)[1]}, inplace= True)
if file == all_files[0]:
    all_states = temp.copy(deep=True)
else:
    temp["Item"] = temp["Item"].str.replace("*", "")
    all_states = pd.merge(all_states, temp, how = 'outer', on = ['S.No.', 'Item'])
del temp
```

The output I get is -

S.No. 1
1.1
1.2
1.3 . . .

1.1. --> Need to get rid of these and consider them as 1.1

The contaminated S.No. forms a new row for a single column. I need it to be in the same rows as others.

I just want the last '.' at the end of the string to be removed and not all.

I tried the below to clean S.No. :

```
temp["S.No."] = temp["S.No."].str.rstrip(".")
temp["S.No."] = temp["S.No."].str.replace(".$", "")
temp["S.No."] = re.sub(r".$", "", str(temp["S.No."]))
```

But none of them work.

The headers:
[image]

Dirty Rows:
[image]

Comment: Try `temp["S.No."] = temp["S.No."].astype(int)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are only removing one `.` if it exists at the end of the string:

```py
def clean_s_no(text):
    return re.sub('\.$', '', text)
```

Note the `\` (escape character) and `$` (end of string).

Then, apply the function to all the rows on this column:

```py
temp["S.No."] = temp["S.No."].apply(lambda x: clean_s_no(x), axis=1)
```

or

```py
temp["S.No."] = temp["S.No."].apply(clean_s_no, axis=1)
```

Comment: I just want to remove the dot which is the end character of the string and not all.

Comment: @ShreyasPara I have amended my answer based on your clarification.

Comment: Thank you Zac but it gives me an error - TypeError: clean_s_no() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
And if I remove 'axis', it does nothing.

Comment: Zac, there is no issue with your code or the one I tried. The file had an issue, the '.' was not the last character, it had four trailing spaces.

Comment: @ShreyasPara I recommend using https://regexr.com/ to figure out the appropriate regular expression that matches what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are column "S.No." is string type then try the following:

```
temp.loc[temp["S.No."].str.contains('.'), 'S.No.'] = temp["S.No."].str.replace(".","")
```

You can change the column type to string by

```
temp["S.No."] = temp["S.No."].astype(str)
```

Comment: It is a string but only some of them have '.' at the end which needs to be removed.

Comment: this "temp.loc[temp["S.No."].str.contains('.'), 'S.No.']" part will only select those who have '.' in them and then this "temp["S.No."].str.replace(".","")" part will replace '.' to blank. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

the issue was that the '.' at the end had another 4 trailing spaces which went unnoticed.

So after removing those spaces with -

```
temp["S.No."] = temp["S.No."].str.strip()
```

All the mentioned methods work.
I used -

```
temp["S.No."] = temp["S.No."].str.rstrip(".")
```